# Telerik Reporting textbox truncation

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I've searched but couldn't find the answer or even a hint about this problem I'm having. The right side of a textbox truncates the text. The textbox is set to be multiline and wrap text. The odd thing is, if I highlight the text and then copy/paste into Notepad ++, the 'missing' text is actually there.

This leads me to believe that it is a visual issue. I've tried everything I can possibly think of. The textbox's right border is showing 0.0in and the row in which it sits is set at 10.5in.

The only thing I was able to do to make it work was to make the row longer than 10.5in but that creates an issue with printing.

Does anyone happen to have any more suggestions?

Comment: add a breakpoint after a text is set, and se if the control have the text in it properties.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, the textbox does have all of the text in it. It is purely a visual thing. I cannot figure out how to fix this without making the entire report width 10.6in. Doing that will cause problems with printing unfortunately.

Comment: How is this both a C# and VB.NET question? What kind of textbox is it? How is telerik important?

Comment: It's a Telerik Report. The textbox is a Telerik.Reporting.TextBox control. It could be either c# OR vb. It isn't specific to either one actually.

Comment: If I knew how to add images, I'd share a screenshot to make the issue more understandable.